# Inserting images in powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

For example if I insert picture in powerpoint name of that picture is changing but I want to be a same. Anyone knows how that works? Is changing name based on what?
Thank you

Comment: Are you inserting the picture via code?  If so, quote the code you're using.  PowerPoint assigns a name whenever you insert any shapes, pictures, whatever.  You can change the name programmatically; you cannot have two shapes with the same name on one slide.

Comment: I'm just asking what is the logic behind the scene. If maybe powerpoint renaming images based on some tags of images, I can easily change that without vba code. I want same shape with same name on 150 slides, and that's the reason why Im asking. If only the option vba I will try to write some code.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a picture onto a slide that contains nothing else, the new picture will be named Picture 1.

If you insert a picture onto a slide that contains two other shapes, the new picture will be named Picture 3.

In other words, the new shape will be named ShapeType & ShapeCount.